# Laravel 5.2 flash session logs user out

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect

I have weird bug where if I use

```
 $msg = "Success";
 return redirect("")->with("msg_g" , $msg);
```

The code works as expected, however if I add spaces inside msg:

```
$msg = "Success Value"; // This part logs user out
return redirect("")->with("msg_g" , $msg);
```

The user gets logged out. Does anyone have any clue of why this might be happening? I've checked laravel docs at

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data and it does not say anything about values with spaces.

Also this bug occurs if I $key name would be too long

Comment: Have you checked all other variables that might influence the user login?

Comment: No I haven't, what should I check for?

Comment: Do a trial and error if you can't figure it out straight. Keep the above code as is and try commenting other parts of the code in the same method, or check in the controller to whom you have redirected

Comment: Use a proper debugger (xdebug), set a few breakpoints and step through the code. A debugger is a must for developing any non trivial application

Comment: I've did trial and error, it all came down that different sized strings seem to log the user out and I cant seem to find reason why this is happening.